# İs there a way to revert to last hard save?

Tags: auto-save, backup

If I understand correctly `M-x revert-buffer` reverts to the last auto saved buffer, as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html#Reverting).

I just lost a big file (it was garbled for some reason). I opened the auto back up file but it was empty except a few lines. I was saving frequently with `C-x C-s`, is there a way to revert back to one of the states I saved?

And is there a way to save to the back up file manually?

Comment: It's not too clear to me what you did. If you saved using `C-x C-s`, and if that saved file is what you want, then just open it and ignore any auto-save file that might be more recent. When you try to open that saved file you'll be prompted, asking if you instead want to open the autosaved file (which is more recent). At that prompt, just say no.

Comment: The buffer was open, it seems that I entered a corrupted macro and instead of publishing, it gave me the message saying "the end of file is reached" and the whole file was garbled (sentences mixed up, random repetitions etc.). I was hoping to revert to a previously saved state.

Comment: You should just undo it. Default keybinding is `C-/`.

Comment: I tried undo, it made things worse. And also I think there is a limit to how many undo's you can do. After a few undo's it started to redo. The whole file was garbled.

Comment: `revert-buffer` updates the buffer to reflect any changes in the underlying file, not "to the last auto saved buffer": if the underlying file has changed drastically, then the buffer will of course change, but the changes are grouped as a single undo group, so undoing as @db48x suggested, should get your buffer back to its former state. You should then *STOP* and think hard before proceeding further. You might want to examine the file (e.g. `foo.txt`), any backup that exists (`foo.txt~`) and any auto-saved files (`#foo.txt#`) - best to do that outside of emacs by using `cat` in a terminal.

Comment: The most important suggestion is to *NOT* try things blindly: you end up digging a deeper hole that way. If you stop and think and take stock of the situation, you can often recover even from seemingly major disasters.

Comment: You can also use either `M-x diff-buffer-with-file` or `M-x ediff-current-file` to compare the current buffer to the saved file.

Comment: The file on the filesystem *is* "the last hard save", so a reasonable first step might be to make a copy of that file outside of Emacs.  If you were "saving frequently with C-x C-s" *after* corrupting the file, and the extent of the changes exceeds the amount of undo state being retained by Emacs (which can happen for large changes) then you're into "backup file" territory.

Comment: I would start reading `C-h i g (emacs)Backup` and check your backup config and figure out whether you have any useful backups pre-dating the corruption.  If not, and if you don't have a backup strategy outside of Emacs, then you might be out of luck.  If it's a serious disaster then (a) you could talk to data recovery services (this will be expensive); and (b) make sure that you sort out a backup process as a priority to prevent future disasters.

Comment: @phils Thanks. I read `C-h i g (emacs)Backups` and according this sentence: "However, if you kill the buffer and then visit the file again, a new backup file will be made." This may be helpful. But when I tested it, it saved the file after killing and opening a couple of times, not once. As you say, the best is to have a backup process outside emacs. What do you recommend?

Comment: Also, I found that `C-u C-x C-s` marks the file to be saved to the backup file with the next save. This is helpful.